# How to convert Php array into a Javascript array and draw in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am currently having problem converting from Php array to Javascript array,
My array in php looks like this:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 2019-01-10-12:15,1
    [1] => 2019-01-10-12:15,1.5
    [2] => 2019-01-10-12:15,2.1
    [3] => 2019-01-10-12:15,1.3

)
```

And I have tried so many way I have found online but with no luck (such as json_encode and then JSON.parse). I need to convert above into a JS array. Struggle for a long time but could not figure out. Thank you!

Comment: `var a = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;` generally works (no quotes, no parsing the json), how did you try using it.  IE> can you show us the Javascirpt code your trying to put it into.

Comment: I don't know why if I used json_encode() it automatically generate quotes on my Php array. It looked like jsArr = new Array("["2019-01-10-12:15,1\r","2019-01-10-12:15,1.5\r","2019-01-10-12:15,2.1\r","2019-01-10-12:15,1.3\r"]");  and giving me Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: What's this `new Array(`  Not needed as it's already an array.

Comment: I have removed new Array(), and now I have "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number".

Comment: I found why, it is the problem of quotes, I should use " instead of '. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use in PHP:

```
$js = json_encode($obj);
```

In JavaScript:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(' ... YOUR JSON STRING FROM PHP ... ');
```

==================

Your code:

```
var obj = new Array('["2019-01-10-12:15,1\r", .... "2019-01-10-12:15,1.3\r"]');
```

will result nested arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP, `json_encode` should work perfectly - just assign it to a variable like so:

```
var myArray = <?php echo json_encode($myArray); ?>;
```

Comment: I have tried this method but it gave me Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list  var jsArr = new Array("["2019-01-10-12:15,1\r","2019-01-10-12:15,1.5\r","2019-01-10-12:15,2.1\r","2019-01-10-12:15,1.3\r"]");

Comment: In Javascript or in PHP?

Comment: It is giving me Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list from JS, and after using js array. it looked like jsArr = new Array("["2019-01-10-12:15,1\r","2019-01-10-12:15,1.5\r","2019-01-10-12:15,2.1\r","2019-01-10-12:15,1.3\r"]");

Comment: Well, that is an error in your JavaScript code - and the array is working as well. Please post the rest of your JavaScript code so we may identify any additional errors.

Comment: This js file contains only this line so far, I was trying to convert from Php array into Js array then draw the graphthrough Highcharts.

Comment: I found why, it is the problem of quotes, I should use " instead of '. Thanks